# Can a system have processors both with and without Hyper Threading?

Tags: cpu, multi-processor

Is is ever possible that a given computer has several processors among which only some have Hyper Threading technology and others do not?

My problem is that I use hardcore code [like here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/associate-logical-processors-to-physical-processors/) for identifying which logical processors map to which physical cores. This code misbehaves when run in a virtual machine. My current intent is to first check whether the processor has Hyper Threading at all but I need to be sure that all other processors in the system also have (or not have) Hyper Threading.

Is it possible that only some processors in a system have Hyper Threading and others do not?

Comment: This should probably be asked at stackoverflow.com

Comment: Nope, that's not programming related, it's a pure hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most common kind of multi CPU support is [Symmetric Multiprocessing (SMP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) which requires identical processors.  I believe this is true for Windows and most Linux distributions.

Comment: right - mixing CPUs is highly frowned-upon; they need to bethe same everything - cache, speed, number of cores, etc

Comment: @warren They sometimes need to be the same revision number of a particular processor as a friend of mine found out to his cost.  I remember seeing a chart he found showing which revisions of a Pentium II-300 would SMP happily together.